# Spring boot JDBC Oracle Database - Table or View not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oracle-sqldeveloper, crud-repository

I need to create a new Table inside a existing Database to save Data using Spring Boot.

I created the Table and granted all rights i need to the specific user (insert, update, delete, select).

In my Project i created the Entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(schema = "Schema-Name", name = "Name-Of-Table")
public class test{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.Identity)
private Long id;
}
```

TestRepository:

```
public interface TestRepository extends CrudRepository<Test, Long> {}
```

if i try to create an instance of Test with `Test test = new test();` and add all needed parameters like `test.setId((long)1);` and execute that, i get a `ORA-00942: Table or View not found` exception.

If i create an example Row inside SQL Developer with `insert into` it works fine. Also if i try to read the data in my code via an `@Autowired TestRepository` with `testRepository.findById((long)1)` i receive the correct Values.

Why cant i "wirte" into the Table? I can read but i cant write. On write it says "Table or View not found").
When i look into the current "Access`" of the Table i can clearly see that the User has the rights to Insert, Update, Select and Delete.

Thanks for helping

EDIT:

DDL of the Table

```
CREATE TABLE "SERVICE"."OTES_OE_TESTFALL" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(19,0) DEFAULT "SERVICE"."OTES_OE_TESTFALL_SEQUENCE".nextval NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "TESTFALL_ID" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "OE_JSON" CLOB, 
    "EDCOM_ID" VARCHAR2(128 BYTE), 
     PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SERVICE_DATA"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SERVICE_DATA"   NO INMEMORY 
 LOB ("OE_JSON") STORE AS SECUREFILE (
  TABLESPACE "SERVICE_DATA" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192
  NOCACHE LOGGING  NOCOMPRESS  KEEP_DUPLICATES 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 106496 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)) ;


  GRANT DELETE ON "SERVICE"."OTES_OE_TESTFALL" TO "SERVICE";
  GRANT INSERT ON "SERVICE"."OTES_OE_TESTFALL" TO "SERVICE";
  GRANT SELECT ON "SERVICE"."OTES_OE_TESTFALL" TO "SERVICE";
  GRANT SELECT ON "SERVICE"."OTES_OE_TESTFALL" TO "SERVICE_LESEN";
  GRANT UPDATE ON "SERVICE"."OTES_OE_TESTFALL" TO "SERVICE";
```

Comment: `@Table(schema = "Schema-Name", name = "Name-Of-Table")` -- is that literally what the code says? Do you have a schema named `Schema-Name` and a table named `Name-Of-Table`?

Comment: No it was an example. The name is exactly the name of the Table in oracle. And of course there is the right schema name as well

Comment: Well, please don't do that.  Code you share should be the ***real, actual*** code.  Obfuscating elements without indicating they are obfuscated just means people will misinterpret it.

Comment: Can you post the DDL for the table?

Comment: I added the DDL. @JimGarrison how do i indicate that i obfuscated some code parts?